# How to avoid openSSH showing authentication popup?

Tags: 10.04, openssh

When pushing a bzr repo to another server, I need to type an openSSH password.

After I typed it, an openSSH popup appears, and requires the password again.

Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, that even with an SSH key, if you put a passcode on the ssh key you use, it'll require you to enter your passcode to unlock the key once during your login session (unless otherwise configured).  This is a security measure that some people enable so that others cant utilize their system nor their SSH key on their own system.

**EDIT**
In order to fix this, you'd need to edit your SSH key (if you use one) so that it does not require a passcode, and `seahorse` (the GUI for key management and things) will help you do that.  I strongly recommend you don't remove your passcode from your SSH key (if that IS the thing that's causing the popups, and I'm pretty sure it is)

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: The way I read the question, it's likely the user does not have a key at all.

Comment: @Mikel: no need to comment about your interpretation after posting your answer, I can clearly see your interpretation of their question through your answer.

Comment: @Mikel: EvilPhoenix is correct, actually.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: My answer was directed to the Adam Matan; my comment was directed to EvilPhoenix.  I think this is the logical thing to do.

Comment: @Mikel: nvm lol...

Comment: @Roland Taylor: Besides, nobody has starred this question, so if I had not started my comment with @username, he probably wouldn't have seen my comment or answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

By saying "password", I assume this means you don't have an SSH key.

The easiest way to make this work:

1. Open a terminal window and run `ssh-keygen`
2. Accept the default location
3. Enter a password or passphrase twice (passphrase is like a password, but can contain spaces)
4. Run `ssh-copy-id OTHERSERVER` and enter your password
5. Run `ssh OTHERSERVER`

Now, it should ask you for the passphrase you typed.

After that, gnome-keyring-daemon or ssh-agent will remember your passphrase until you log out.

Answer (score -1):

You may find GPG Agent useful - see [Tips and Tricks page on Ubuntu Community Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto)

Comment: How does it solve the popup problem?

Comment: The popup will appear only once - to unlock the key - and the key will be used up to 24 hours or before the log off

Comment: Why should it interfere with my commandline anyway?

Comment: If you're using a regular password, it will prompt every time.  You need to use public key authentication, and `gpg-agent` so SSH can get at the stored key.  In general, pubic keys are strongly preferred.

Comment: How will `gpg-agent` help with SSH?  Do you mean `ssh-agent`?